# What is the best practice for handling a form?

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react and the way I handle a form to make a request is the following:
let's imagine that I have a form that have 3 inputs: Name, Lastname, Phone

I use a react hook state to save the data

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    lastname: "",
    phone: "",
});
```

Then to handle the data from the input I use the next function:

```
const handle = (e) => {
    const getData = {...form};
    getData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setForm(getData);
}
```

and the input have something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" required onChange={(e) => handle(e)} />
```

Should I keep using this or what do you recommend me?

Comment: This is good enough, I'd recommend [`formik`](https://formik.org/) to handle forms. It's structure is a lot like the way you outlined, but it reduces a lot of the boilerplate, and it has some nice features out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong how you handle the form. But when it comes to bigger applications *formik* is a one of popular library use. Also you can have custom hook to handle forms if you want. For a example,

```
const useForm = (initialValues) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  }
  
  return [values, onChangeHandler];
}
```

In your component

```
const [values, onChangeHandler] = useForm({ name: "", lastname: "", phone: "", })
```